# Why we use two photodiodes as optoisolator or optocoupler?

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb, diodes, opto-isolator, optoelectronics

Why do we need two photodiodes in order to create an optoisolator or optocoupler? Many sources say that it is to compensate for the non-linearity of the diodes, but is there any explanation based on an equation or any scientific proof regarding this matter?

Comment: You don't need two.

Comment: Detailed examples, please.

Comment: I found this in wikipedia:
"Photodiode opto-isolators can be used for interfacing analog signals, although their non-linearity invariably distorts the signal. A special class of analog opto-isolators introduced by Burr-Brown uses two photodiodes and an input-side operational amplifier to compensate for diode non-linearity. One of two identical diodes is wired into the feedback loop of the amplifier, which maintains overall current transfer ratio at a constant level regardless..."

How can I prove that non-linearity can be fixed with Burr-Brown technique?

Answer (score 9):

I think you might be referring to an analogue signal opto isolation technique like this: -

[image]

The op-amp on the left is driving an analogue signal across the optical barrier and, to make sure the photodiode on the right is getting the correct signal level, it uses a local reference photodiode and senses the light it emits. In that way, if temperature (for instance) affects the LED light output, it can be compensated for.

They are pretty good (better than 1% linearity in many cases) but not as good as digitizing the signal and sending logic streams at high speed.

Comment: I referred to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator#Photodiode_opto-isolators. The article mentioned that we need two photodiodes to compensate non-linearity characteristic of diode. Can I proof this compensation technique by equation?

Comment: @JeffLGaol If you look at the picture in my answer you will see that U1 is driven by Vin and, due to negative feedback, Vb MUST equal Vin (Va). If the photodiodes are perfectly matched, R1=R2 and Vcc on both sides of the barrier is equal in value then Vout will equal Vin. That is a word-like proof that you could mathematically formulate but you will need to consider op-amp errors such as differences in input offset voltages and input bias currents. Do you understand how op-amps work when connected with negative feedback like this?

Answer (score 4):

To make a simple opto-isolator, only one LED and one diode is required. This is the normal, common type. It can be used for digital signals, and crude analogue transmission, where the linearity of the signal getting through is not important.

If you want to transmit an analogue signal with good linearity, then a second diode is used in feedback to control the LED current. Now the linearity depends on the balance of the two diodes, rather than the linearity of the LED and diode curves.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I was wondering. Can I proof that the second diode can compensate the non-linearity by equation? My lecture only gave me clue that it was something related to this equation "I = I' * e^(V/V')".

Comment: @JeffLGaol The second diode only compensates for the non-linearity of the first if a) they are similar and b) they are running at similar currents. As neither of those will be exactly true, the compensation will only be approximate. The better the diodes, and their currents, are balanced, the better will be the compensation. There's nothing to prove by equation, unless you want to write down a tautology.

Answer (score 3):

Normal run-of-the-mill optoisolators usually have one phototransistor, the rest have one photodiode.

[image]

There are is one kind of optoisolator with two photodiodes,  as shown above: The IL300

These are matched so you can transfer an analog signal across the isolated divide with light. If there were only one photodiode without the feedback photodiode it would be very difficult to drive the LED with the correct current to match the voltage on the other side of the divide.

Other than that if there are "two diodes" in a package they are modeled as one diode. I have not seen any diode curves that have a double knee and I don't see a reason for one.

Comment: You don't know the transfer ratio on the day of manufacture. It changes with temperature, and over the long term (10years) the LED's age and output lowers (this sometimes bites digital couplers, optical encoders and so on when thresholds are fixed)

Comment: Thats why you run it in feedback

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the optocoupler could work with only 1 photodiode, the second diode's purpose is to get a reference for feedback and compensation.

What others did not mention yet is that the main reason for using 2 diodes is the large manufacturing deviation in CTR (current transfer ratio). In the 2 diode optocouplers the 2 diodes are formed on the same silicon die, so they are much more similiar in these parameters (plus have always the same temperature, etc.) so they generate pretty much the same current and thats why this construction is more precise.